# Proof of solution for system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, systems-of-equations

I have been given two proof problems that have the same setup and I am not quite sure how to begin proving or disproving them. They both start with Let $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ be elements in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and solutions to the following system of equations. Then $(x_1 + x_2, y_1 + y_2)$ is also a solution to the system of equations. Prove or Disprove this statement.

The first system set is
$$3x + 100y = 0 $$
$$$ -8x + y = 0$$

The second system set is
$$4/3)x + 3y = 7 $$
$$x - 4y = 0$$

I have solved both sets and determine that they both only have one solution, the first set's solution is (0, 0) and the second set's solution is (84/25, 21/25). I am not quite sure how to put into a formal proof that there are not two solutions so there cannot be a solution to the set that is the combination of the solutions.

I would appreciate any help as to how to go about proving or disproving something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement is true.

This is due to the fact that you are in a particular case where you have a **homogeneous system**, meaning zeros on the right hand side of your equations.

The proof of this statement runs as follows:

Consider the *general* homogeneous system:
$$\begin{cases}ax+cy=0\\bx+dy=0\end{cases}\tag{1}$$
Saying that
$$(x_1,y_1) \ \text{and}  \ (x_2,y_2) \ \text{are solutions of (1)} $$

is equivalent to say that:

$$\begin{cases}ax_1+cy_1=0\\bx_1+dy_1=0\end{cases} \ \text{and} \ \begin{cases}ax_2+cy_2=0\\bx_2+dy_2=0\end{cases} \ \text{which implies:}$$

$$\begin{cases}a(x_1+x_2)+c(y_1+y_2)=0\\b(x_1+x_2)+d(y_1+y_2)=0\end{cases}$$

(by adding the two first equations, then the two last equations).

otherwise said, $((x_1+x_2),(y_1+y_2))$ is again a solution of system (1).

**Remark 1:** for a non-homogeneous system :

$$\begin{cases}ax+cy=e\\bx+dy=f\end{cases}$$

with $e\ne 0$ or $f \ne 0$, such a conclusion couldn't have been drawn (adding the equations, we would have obtained $2e, 2f$ instead of $e,f$  in the right hand sides, with at least  $2e \ne e$ or $2f \ne f$).

**Remark 2:** Later on, when you will be learning linear algebra, you will be said that this kind of question deals with the fact that the set of such solutions, called a **kernel**, is a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, therefore stable for addition.

Comment: Thank you! I thought it had something to do with being homogenous and combining the two solution equations but I thought that seemed to easy for the question. I guess I should have trusted myself more

Answer (score 1):

Just .... do it.  Solve it.  And don't call it a "proof"-- you are just doing a specific example.

$3x + 100y = 0 $ and $ and $ -8x + y = 0$.

so $y = 8x$.

so $3x + 100y= 3x + 100\cdot 8x = 0$

so $803x = 0$.

So $x = 0$.

So $y = 8x = 8\cdot 0 = 0$.

So $x=0$ and $y = 0$.  There's *nothing* more to say.